# Using variable in img src or image source in jsp, html

Tags: html, database, jsp

This seems correct to me, but won't work.

What I am trying to do is taking name from database and displaying image of same name in my page.

```
<%
     String imagevariable=("../images/"+ rs.getString("name"));
 %>

 <img src="<%=imagevariable%>" alt="image">
```

Comment: `Inspect` the image and check if you are getting proper path of the image in src?

Comment: Read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370)...

Comment: Look at the HTML source code your JSP is generating. Is the URL correct? Does visiting the URL manually give you the file you expect? Check the Network tab. Does the URL get the HTTP status code you expect? Or does it throw a Not Found, Not Authorised or other error message?